# stop cassandra server on mac os x

Tags: cassandra

How do I stop cassandra server running on a single node in my mac os x? 
Cassandra script doesn't have -stop option. Only way other than restart the mac os x, was to do a "ps" and find the java process which had arguments for cassandra and use kill -9 to kill the process.

But trying to restart cassandra after that still throws

`Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use`.

Anybody seen it? Any quick solutions?

Comment: I also would like to know... the CONTROL-C does not work on MAC OSX as mentioned in the getting started docs.

Comment: Michael, usually I start it with ./cassandra and don't pass the -f flag for the process to be in the foreground. So, control-c won't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

EDIT: I actually find this much more useful.

Open terminal and type:

$ ps -ax | grep cassandra

gives you a list of pids running with the name cassandra.

Use the PID number to kill the process for example here is a returned value:
708 ttys000    0:03.10 /usr/bin/java -ea -javaagent:Downloads/Web/Cassandra/dsc-cassandra-1.1.0/bin/

$ kill 708

---

Old post:

After posting my comment I found a stop-server script in the BIN.

You have to open up the script and comment out the code if you want to use that script. But here is what it says inside the script.

```
 echo "please read the stop-server script before use"

    # if you are using the cassandra start script with -p, this
    # is the best way to stop:

     kill `cat <pidfile>` 


    # otherwise, you can run something like this, but
    # this is a shotgun approach and will kill other processes
    # with cassandra in their name or arguments too:

    # user=`whoami`
    # pgrep -u $user -f cassandra | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: FYI I commented out the kill 'cat <pidfile>' to show what needed to be commented out.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the answer. I did use kill process command as mentioned in my question but found that the data had got corrupt. Could be someother reason, but yeah kill command by passing the PID definitely stops the server.

Answer (score 27):

If you've installed cassandra via homebrew, use `brew info cassandra` and it will tell you how to load/unload cassandra using launchctl.  This worked better for me than the other answers here.

Commands

`brew info cassandra` To see status of cassandra

`brew services start cassandra` To start cassandra

`brew services stop cassandra` To stop cassandra

Comment: `brew services stop cassandra` works perfectly for me

Answer (score 22):

Found this solution elsewhere which seems to work!

`pkill -f 'java.*cassandra'`

Worth a try!
This works on the Ubuntu I have. Not on MacOS!

On Mac one more is `ps -af | grep cassandra` and then using kill. But, it does not work sometimes!

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to see which OS process has the Cassandra port open, like this:

```
lsof -i :9160
```

Sample output:

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    30253 aswan  214u  IPv4 0xffffff80190dcc20      0t0  TCP *:netlock1 (LISTEN)
```

Then you can use "kill -9 [pid]" on that process.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Cassandra's nodetool command, as well.

```
nodetool drain
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about it shutting down, but it works reliably for me with a single node, local server. It generally takes a few seconds to finish the shutdown, however.

Answer (score 0):

kill -9 `` ` acx | grep -i cassandra | awk '{print$1}' `` `

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the new Datastax Enterprise 5.0 version, and it, at least, offers a simple enough command for stopping Cassandra:

```
dse cassandra-stop
```

It takes a few moments to shut down, but it works for me.