# Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2, Cassandra 2.2.3, kill pid not working

Tags: macos, cassandra

Using Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 and started Cassandra ( version 2.2.3) in the terminal by giving "cassandra -f" command.

Cassandra started good and able to connect using cqlsh.
Then quitted cqlsh, so its no more connecting to cassandra @ port 9042

I m now trying to kill the running cassandra by doing the below:

```
ps -ef | grep cassandra
sudo kill -9 PID
```

But it does not kill the process, still cassandra is running. Not sure how to stop it now.

Comment: ps -ef | grep cassandra (first line), sudo kill -9 PID (second line)

Comment: Is `PID` replaced with the actual process ID for cassandra?

Comment: yes, i have used the actual process ID, for example: sudo kill -9 11273

Comment: And it is not the `grep cassandra` PID right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stop cassandra server on mac os x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877072/stop-cassandra-server-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: checked my bin folder and not seeing any script as "stop-server"

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

```
ps aux | grep cassandra
```

Find the PID (it's always the 5 digits and if it have more than one, choose the lower) and then

```
kill <PID>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

The command `ps -ef | grep cassandra` should be returning two PIDs, one for cassandra and another for your grep command which also contains the word cassandra. There's a good chance that you're trying to kill the grep command, which has already died. So, make sure that you're killing the correct process.

Also, if all else fails, you can restart.